# webknights vs urlscan for IIS

Tags: web-hosting, iis-7, iis

I am currently working on a project which will be using IIS as it's main web server facing the internet.  I was hoping to use something like a Web Application Firewall to increase the security stance of IIS.  I am hoping that someone can provide some guidance on which to use and for what reasons.

The two solutions I was looking at was webknights and urlscan, but other options are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

urlscan is simple and supported by MS!

Comment: Can you consider it a Web Application Firewall like webknights claims to be?  How configurable is it?

Comment: sorry I have no idea exactly what webknights does can't find any reference to it on google. Also I would not call urlscan a web app filter.